# Spring Cloud Config server inside a Spring Boot app with MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I'm inserting a Spring Cloud Config server directly into my existing Spring Boot App, by adding the module dependency and `@EnableConfigServer`. Everything works as expected except I just realized that the config server URL mapping is hijacking some of my existing API endpoints due to they are sharing the same `server.port`

For example, I had an existing page at `v1/docs/index.html`, and this will be now mapped automatically to `org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController#labelled` which has

```
    @RequestMapping("/{name}/{profiles}/{label:.*}")
    public Environment labelled(@PathVariable String name, @PathVariable String profiles,
```

Wondering is there anyway I can separate config server to a different port? Or add a special prefix to it to avoid URL mapping conflicts? Or given the current configurability it's just a bad idea to utilizing existing API servers as a config server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer I need after reading the document more carefully:)

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_spring_cloud_config_server

> To change the location of the server endpoints you can (optionally) set spring.cloud.config.server.prefix, e.g. "/config", to serve the resources under a prefix. The prefix should start but not end with a "/". It is applied to the @RequestMappings in the Config Server (i.e. underneath the Spring Boot prefixes server.servletPath and server.contextPath).